# CommandNotFoundError when activate conda with Docker

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile, conda

I am new to `Docker` and try to build the `Docker` image with the activation of the `conda` environment. But I can't.

This is my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM continuumio/miniconda3

COPY . /app

WORKDIR /app

RUN conda env create -f environment.yml

SHELL ["conda", "run", "-n", "FM", "/bin/bash", "-c"]

RUN conda activate FM

ENTRYPOINT ["conda", "run", "-n", "FM", "python", "src/run.py"]
```

My `environment.yml` file:

```
name: FM
channels:
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - _libgcc_mutex=0.1=main
  - ca-certificates=2020.6.24=0
  - certifi=2020.6.20=py37_0
  - ld_impl_linux-64=2.33.1=h53a641e_7
  - libedit=3.1.20191231=h7b6447c_0
  - libffi=3.2.1=hd88cf55_4
  - libgcc-ng=9.1.0=hdf63c60_0
  - libstdcxx-ng=9.1.0=hdf63c60_0
  - ncurses=6.2=he6710b0_1
  - openssl=1.1.1g=h7b6447c_0
  - pip=20.1.1=py37_1
  - python=3.7.6=h0371630_2
  ...
  - pip:
    - click==7.1.2
    - cycler==0.10.0
    - decorator==4.4.2
    - flask==1.1.2
    - imageio==2.9.0
    - itsdangerous==1.1.0
    ...
prefix: /home/huytran/miniconda3/envs/FM
```

When I build the image `docker build -t condatest .`, I get this error:

```
...
Step 5/8 : SHELL ["conda", "run", "-n", "FM", "/bin/bash", "-c"]
 ---> Running in 962623c513cc
Removing intermediate container 962623c513cc
 ---> c5a91349830f
Step 6/8 : RUN conda activate FM
 ---> Running in 1f3d1cd0c50b

CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'.
To initialize your shell, run

    $ conda init <SHELL_NAME>

Currently supported shells are:
  - bash
  - fish
  - tcsh
  - xonsh
  - zsh
  - powershell

See 'conda init --help' for more information and options.

IMPORTANT: You may need to close and restart your shell after running 'conda init'.
```

Do you guys know where I am wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `RUN conda activate FM` doesn't do anything, because it only activates in that particular `RUN`. It has no impact on future `RUN` or `ENTRYPOINT/CMD` commands.

It's also unnecessary, since you're using `conda run` in the entrypoint and using the `SHELL` to enable the environment ala https://pythonspeed.com/articles/activate-conda-dockerfile/.

Just omit it and you'll be fine.